# piping in linux

Tags: shell, pipe

i have a file called test which contains the word "hello" in it.

shouldn't

```
     echo test | cat
```

output hello? since its taking the output from the echo test, which is test, as the input for cat. so essentially im doing cat test.

but the actual output is test, im really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases you might want the argument to be passed through the pipe. This is how you would do that:

```
echo test | xargs cat
```

which will output the *contents* of the file named "test".

Answer (score 2):

Your pipes sends `test` to `cat` as the *input*, not as the *argument*.  You could do:

```
cat `echo test`
```

to control the *argument* to `cat` with `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

`echo` prints its arguments. `cat` prints a file which is by default standard input. When you pipe `echo`'s standard output is connected to `cat`'s standard input.

Correct is simply `cat test`.

Answer (score 1):

From `cat --help`

> If no FILE or when FILE is -, read standard input.

In your case, `cat` reads from stdin, which is `test` and outputs that.